# Is there a way to hide a single tab bar item using React Native Router Flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using React Native Router Flux and have a bottom tab bar. I have a screen set up with a lot of links to other screens on it. If the parent scene isn't added to the tabs, I'm unable to route to it.

I've looked through the documentation and tried various options and styling. I think the easiest option would be to apply a width of 0 to that particular scene group, but it isn't available with View styles.

I want to be able to hide the parent scene so it isn't showing in the tab bar. At the moment, nothing is changing and the item is showing in the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was that I had the child scenes nested within a parent scene. When I removed them from the parent and outside of the tabs, it worked perfectly.